# Using selectors in CSS to target individual elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm currently testing my skills in CSS. I came across this puzzle and I need to find out how to select the individual images on the page using selectors.
This is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <style>
    @keyframes spin{
      from{transform:rotate(0deg)}
      to{transform:rotate(360deg)}
    }

    /*CSS Selector goes here*/{
      animation-name: spin;
      animation-duration:1000ms;
      animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <header>My Tutorial 3</header>
    <img src="H:\ASECOND YEAR\Web Tutorial 3\harley.jpg" />

    <article>
      <header>About this tutorial</header>
      In this tutorial I need to make a picture spin for ever...
      <img src="H:\ASECOND YEAR\Web Tutorial 3\hellcat.jpg" />
    </article>

    <footer>my footer
      <img src="H:\ASECOND YEAR\Web Tutorial 3\smiley.jpg" /></footer>   
  </body>
</html>
```

What I've found out is that I can select the image nested in the article by writing `article img` but I find it difficult to select the other images. I've tried using `header~img` thinking that it would select the first image since the first image is preceded by a `header` tag but it ends up spinning the first and second image. I also tried `img:nth-of-type(2)` thinking it would select the last image (index starts at 0) but it doesn't select any of the images.
Can someone tell me the selectors to use to select each individual image? Selectors are pretty fiddly.

I also found out how to select the last image, I can do this by using `footer img` but when I use `img:last-child`, it spins the middle and last images.

Comment: I've went to w3schools and saw the list of selectors. I've tried using 'body img:last-child' and it does spin the middle and bottom pics but shouldn't it ONLY spin the last image as the last image is the last child in the body tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First lets look at the selectors that you tried and didn't work as per your expectation:

- `header ~ img` - The `~` selector is called the general sibling selector and selects all `img` tags which have `header` as a sibling before it. Both the first image and the second image have a `header` prior to it under the same parent and hence both get selected.
- `img:nth-of-type(2)` - The `nth-*` selectors always work only among elements that share the same parent. The second and third `img` tags are inside different parents (`article` and `footer` respectively). Hence the top most parent has only one `img` element (the one which comes after first `header`) and hence no element matches the `nth-of-type(2)` selector.
- `img:last-child` - The `last-child` selector selects the `img` which is also the last child of every single parent. The first `img` is not the last child under its parent (`body`) because there are some elements after it and so it doesn't get selected. The second and third `img` tags are the last child element present under the `article` and `footer` respectively and hence both get selected.

Now coming to the question on how to select each individual image, there are a variety of different ways to select them and things might change when your markup becomes more complex but as it stands, the following would work:

- First `img` alone can be selected by `body > header + img`.
- Second `img` alone can be selected by `article > header + img` or `article img`.
- Third `img` alone can be selected by `footer > img` or `footer img`.

The key part of the first two selectors is the part that comes before the `header + img` because that narrows down the list of selected items. The first selector selects only `img` tags which immediately follow a `header` and both have `body` as their parent (not grandparent/ancestor). Similarly, second selector selects only `img` tags which immediately follow a `header` and both have `article` as their common parent.

In the below snippet, I have used the above mentioned selectors and added a different colored border to each `img` element to illustrate how they work.

```css
body > header + img {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
article > header + img {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
footer > img {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<header>My Tutorial 3</header>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/1" />

<article>
  <header>About this tutorial</header>
  In this tutorial I need to make a picture spin for ever...
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/2" />
</article>

<footer>my footer
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/3" />
</footer>
```

Comment: Oh i see now. good answer. I was a bit confused between the difference of using ~ and +. So pretty much, we use ~ for siblings and + if it is nested; e.g. li tags inside a ul tag?

Comment: @TarikhChouhan: Actually no, both `~` and `+` select only siblings (which means they must share same parent). The reason why the `+` works in the answer is because of the part before the `header + img`. That narrows down the selected element based on what is its parent. So, first one selects only `img` whose parent is `body` whereas second selects only `img` whose parent is `article`.